# Arduino Every Nano with 3.7V Li-Po - Reading voltage

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-measurement, lipo

I have Arduino Every Nano and 3.7V Li-Po battery (Akyga LP903759). I want to read the current voltage of a battery using analog pin. If I use a 50 kOhm and 200 kOhm resistor (in voltage divider) I'll get 2.96V on the output. In Arduino datasheet I see than typical resistance which works with this microcontroller is 40 Ohm (Min-20 Ohm, Max-60 Ohm). Could I damage Arduino using this resistor and giving almost 3V to analog pin? Do you know how to get properly values of resistors to read battery level with this Li-Po battery?

Comment: The ATmega4809 does seem to improve on a lot of the shortcomings of the ATmega328p.  In terms of your question though first this board is not specified for operation from a single cell - it's a 5v design with a regulator input from 7v minimum to a (dubiously credible) 12v max.    Have you reworked it?   Where *exactly* does the 40 ohm figure come from?   Some MCUs do indeed have surprisingly low input impedance in some modes, but it's not clear that this chip differs from the typically high impedance earlier ATmegas.

Comment: I'm using booster (sparkfun PAM2401) to have 5V supplied to Arduino, so I need to measure voltage supplied to input of the charger/booster to get appropriate values, 40ohm comes from this datasheet [link] http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42363-SAM-D11_Datasheet.pdf (page 869).

Comment: That data sheet has nothing to do with the Arduino Nano Every, which uses an ATmega4809 not a SAMD11.  Did you misidentify your board, or pull up the wrong data sheet?

Comment: I pulled up the wrong datasheet. My fault

Comment: If you are looking for the correct datasheet, here you are: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega4808-4809-Data-Sheet-DS40002173A.pdf
You should be able to safely use these resitors. However, you might wanna consider resistors of 5 KOhm and 20 KOhm since you will draw a bit more current but you will be a bit less vulnerable to noise. 
The 20-60Ohm you were reading were the caracteristics of the internal pull-up/down, which you can use when reading a pushbutton. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pull-up-resistors/all

Comment: Thanks for the help :)